# Constantly print some info while executing a method in java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler

I have a scheduled java method which executes twice a day at a particular time, does some processing and usually takes around an hour to complete.

Now, during this hour, I need to print some method information out in a text file say every 15 minutes (basically serving as meta information, some variable value that changes during the processing), so this will print 4 times for a particular method.

I have written a separate method for printing but am not sure how to integrate it with my scheduled method above. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainClass {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void print(){
         timer.schedule (new MyTask(),0,1000*60*15);
    }
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
          PrintWriter writer =  null;
          String configurationFilePath ="job-configurations.txt";
          try{
              File file = new File(configurationFilePath);
              if(!file.exists()){
                  file.createNewFile();
              }
              writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
              writer.println("User Agent: "+ useragent);

              writer.println("Location: "+country);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              LOGGER.error("Unable to add UA/Loc log file " + e.getMessage());
          } finally {
               if(writer != null){
                  writer.close();
               }
          }
      }
```

}

How can i call this `print` method of main class and make it stop when the scheduled method completes execution.

Comment: Could you please provide some details about the method running twice a day: how is it scheduled (do you use a `Timer`)? Is it possible for it to schedule call methods of `MainClass`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make 2 static methods in Main class one to start print another to stop print and can call them from another class..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainClass {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void startPrint(){
         timer.schedule (new MyTask(),0,1000*60*15);
    }

    public static void stopPrint() {
        timer.cancel();
    }
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
          PrintWriter writer =  null;
          String configurationFilePath ="job-configurations.txt";
          try{
              //start timer
              MainClass.startPrint();
              File file = new File(configurationFilePath);
              if(!file.exists()){
                  file.createNewFile();
              }
              writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");

              writer.println("User Agent: "+ useragent);

              writer.println("Location: "+country);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              LOGGER.error("Unable to add UA/Loc log file " + e.getMessage());
          } finally {
               if(writer != null){
                  writer.close();
               }

               //Stop Timer
               MainClass.stopPrint();
          }
      }

}
```